# How to increment by a number in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I would like to know how to increment by X amount a number, in other languages I used to do

**foo += 0.1;**

but I have not idea how it can be done in Clojure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables are immutable in Clojure. So you should not try to change the value of `foo`, but instead, "create" a new foo:

```
(def foo2 (+ foo 0.1))
```

...or, if in a loop, recur with a new value:

```
(loop [foo 5.0]
  (when (< foo 9)
    (recur (+ foo 0.1))))
```

...or, if foo is an atom, `swap!` it with a new value:

```
(def foo (atom 5.0))
(swap! foo (partial + 0.1))
```

I recommend you start by reading [the rationale of Clojure](http://clojure.org/rationale).

Comment: Showing vars as the only way to create a new value is misleading -- in most cases where one wants to replace a value with another, they're the wrong tool. Atoms, loops, etc. should probably have a more prominent place in the examples.

Comment: [`swap!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/swap!) takes a function and arguments to make the update, so you can write it like this instead of using `partial`: `(swap! foo + 0.1)`

Answer (score 4):

Blacksad's answer covers defining vars so I would just like to add the other scopes in which you may wish to have a value that is incremented from another value:

within a function's local scope:

```
user> (defn my-function [x]
        (let [y (inc x)
              z (+ x y)]
          [x y z]))
#'user/my-function
user> (my-function 4)
[4 5 9]
```

and If you want to build a value incrementally to make the process more clear:

```
user> (defn my-function [x]
        (let [y (inc x)
               z (+ x y)
               z (+ z 4)
               z (* z z)]
          [x y z]))
#'user/my-function
user> (my-function 4)
[4 5 169]
```

This can make the process more presentable, though it is not a "way to get variables back" and is really only useful in limited contexts. This pattern is used in clojure.core's threading macros.

Comment: let is a macro that produces a call to let* https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c6756a8bab137128c8119add29a25b0a88509900/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4035